# Why overloaded methods have lower priority than instance method

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, overriding

I have base class `A`

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Method(A parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
    public virtual void Method(B parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
}
```

Inhereted `B`

```
public class B : A
{
    public virtual void Method(object parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }

    public override void Method(A parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }

    public override void Method(B parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
}
```

Static class `S` with extension method

```
public static class S
{
    public static void Method(this B instance, B parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
    }
}
```

Example we create instance of type `B` and invoke `Method` on it, we expect that it will be `public override void Method(B parameter)` actual result is `public virtual void Method(object parameter)`.

```
var b = new B();
b.Method(new B()); // B.Method (Object parameter) Why???
```

Why compiler doesn't select more suitible method??? 
**UPD** And why it is not extension method?

Comment: `B` is not nested but inherited.

Comment: extension method isn't called if object have method by same name. this is to avoid breaking old code where expectation is to call old method and not new extension one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why compiler doesn't select more suitible method?

Because it's following the rules of the language specification, where any candidate methods *originally declared* in a base class (over if they're overridden in a derived class) are ignored when finding a candidate method, unless the derived class doesn't have any applicable methods, at which point the search moves up to the base class, etc.

This is [designed to avoid the "brittle base class" problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/04/future-breaking-changes-part-three.aspx), but I find that hard to swallow in the face of the method being overridden in the derived class.

The relevant bit of the C# 4 specification is 7.4, which ends with this:

> For member lookups in types other than type parameters and interfaces, and member lookups in interfaces that are strictly single-inheritance (each interface in the inheritance chain has exactly zero or one direct base interface), the effect of the lookup rules is simply that derived members hide base members with the same name or signature.

EDIT: About extension methods...

> And why it is not extension method?

From section 7.6.5.2 of the spec:

> In a method invocation (§7.5.5.1) of one of the forms
>
> ```
> expr . identifier ( )
> expr . identifier ( args )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )
> expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )
> ```
>
> if the normal processing of the invocation finds no applicable methods, an attempt is made to process the construct as an extension method invocation

So an extension method is *only* used as a last resort, basically.

Comment: I think the question is why is the code calling the inherited method, rather than the extension method, but it's hard to tell?

Comment: @podiluska: I think the extension method is a red herring. The OP doesn't appear to expect it to be called...

Comment: It also interesting why extension method are not called too.

Comment: @user854301: That one's simple: the member lookup steps *only* try to find an extension method after "normal" lookup has failed.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: i still can't got it. i've read the article about *"brittle base class"* and think that understood it. But here we have overrided methods in the `B` class and they suits and they *hide base members with the same name or signature* but why compiler doesn't want to take them? i will appreciate if you give some example that could show why it done in this way and not in another.