# Call Method overloaded from abstract class

Tags: c#

I need to call a Method of a an abstract class implementation. But the compiler always defaults to use the overloaded method from the concrete class, since the signature just requires an inherited type.

Just have a look at the code:

-- This is obviously a vastly simplified version of the actual code that I'm using ;)

```
public class ModelBase { }
public class ModelA : ModelBase { }
public interface IInterface<in TModel>
{
    void Do(TModel model);
}
public abstract class AbstractClass<TModel> : IInterface<TModel>
{
    public abstract void Do(TModel model);
}
public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<ModelA>, IInterface<ModelBase>
{
    public override void Do(ModelA model)
    {
        // I'd like to invoke this method
    }

    public void Do(ModelBase model)
    {
        // how do I invoke the method above??
        Do((ModelA)model);
    }
}
```

^^ This results in a recursion

What I've tried is:

```
((IClass<ModelA>)this).Do((ModelA)model);
```

^^ doesn't change anything

```
base.Do((ModelA)model);
```

^^ throws an error "Cannot call an abstract base member: 'AbstractClass.Do(ModelA)'"

**How do I call the "public override void Do(ModelA model)" method?**

---

btw.
If I change the class to this

```
public class ConcreteClass : IInterface<ModelA>, IInterface<ModelBase>
```

it works.

Comment: This looks like a bug from the compiler overload resolver... What am i missing

Comment: If I may, why do you have an overload that leverages the base type but then makes a call assuming that type is a ModelA? The way the overload is setup, I could give you a ModelB.

Comment: Very valid question @neoistheone . Basically I have an IRepository<Order> that is being requested. A ConcreteRepository<ITOrder> is delivered. Now an Insert method is called on the Repository interface. Even though it is contravariant, I can't cast the IRepository<ITOrder> to the IRepository<Order>. therefor I have to add the IRepository<Order> inheritance to the concrete repository.

Comment: I think the reason this is happening is from the overload resolution rules, specifically from [7.5.5.1 of the C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691356%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) _"If N is applicable with respect to A (Section 7.4.2.1), then all methods declared in a base type of T are removed from the set."_ In this case, there _is_ a valid method on `ConcreteClass`, and the `override` method you want to call actually belongs to the base `AbstractClass<TModel>` so it's ignored. EDIT: Also the overloading rules might treat both methods as "equally applicable"; not sure though.

Comment: I agree @ChrisSinclair . But I wouldn't have guessed that the implementation of the abstract method was considered to be of the base class!

Comment: @Sam7: IIRC, the method "belongs" to the base class. I could be wrong though; I know the overload resolution rules are tricky with lovely edge cases such as these and I haven't gotten them down 100%. For example, as [DavidN linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110565/why-overloaded-methods-have-lower-priority-than-instance-method), Jon Skeet quotes _other_ rules for a similar situation. But I couldn't tell you for sure if this is the _same_ situation, or the same rules apply, or if I'm misinterpreting or using the _wrong_ rules here. Just guessing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cast `this` to `AbstractClass<ModelA>` before call:

```
public void Do(ModelBase model)
{
    ((AbstractClass<ModelA>)this).Do((ModelA)model);
}
```

Comment: Yep, was going to post the same thing. Here's a good post for understanding base vs instance method resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110565/why-overloaded-methods-have-lower-priority-than-instance-method

Comment: Thanks! I was so close with '((IClass<ModelA>)this).Do((ModelA)model);' :)

Answer (score 4):

Use named parameters:

```
public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<ModelA>, IInterface<ModelBase>
{
    public override void Do(ModelA modelA) // change 'model' into 'modelA'
    {
        // I'd like to invoke this method
    }

    public void Do(ModelBase model)
    {
        // how do I invoke the method above??
        Do(modelA : (ModelA)model);
    }
}
```

Now, the compiler knows that you want to call the `Do(ModelA)` method and not the `Do(ModelBase)` method.

Answer (score 3):

Try to implement the interface explicitly. From now on you can call the method `IInterface<ModelBase>.Do(ModelBase model)` only from a reference of type `IInterface<ModelBase>`

```
public class ModelBase { }
public class ModelA : ModelBase { }
public interface IInterface<in TModel>
{
    void Do(TModel model);
}
public abstract class AbstractClass<TModel> : IInterface<TModel>
{
    public abstract void Do(TModel model);
}
public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass<ModelA>, IInterface<ModelBase>
{
    public override void Do(ModelA model)
    {
        Console.Write("Do - Override AbstractClass<ModelA> ");
    }

    void IInterface<ModelBase>.Do(ModelBase model)
    {
        Console.Write("Do - IInterface<ModelBase> ");
        Do(model as ModelA);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var modelA = new ModelA();

    (new ConcreteClass() as IInterface<ModelBase>).Do(modelA); //output -> Do - IInterface<ModelBase> Do - Override AbstractClass<ModelA> 
    Console.WriteLine();
    new ConcreteClass().Do(modelA); //output -> Do - Override AbstractClass<ModelA> 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I might actually go with this solution. :)

Comment: By the way, pay attention to this Do(model as ModelA); because you can't be sure that the variable model is an instance of ModelA or one of its subclasses